# Mold on homemade sriracha

Tags: fermentation, chili-peppers, hot-sauce

We found a recipe online for homemade sriracha hot sauce.

> 3lbs red jalapeños
> 1 cup brown sugar
> ⅛ cup salt

Everything was blended together, then set in a dark closet. The lid is not airtight but has an elastic band holding it shut. This was to let pressure escape as the recipe suggested.

It was supposed to be left for 2 weeks in a dark place. It has been one week but I am worried about the mold on the top.

After about 2-3 days it had a white layer. I read this might be yeast so ignored it. However, it now has fuzzy black mold and I am worried.

Most hot sauce recipes I see need vinegar or something to keep it from rotting but apparently this fermentation method works fine.

Is this sriracha still ok? Can we scrape the mold off after 1 more week?

[image: sriracha early]

[image: sriracha first mold]

[image: sriracha much mold]

Comment: Sriracha costs like, a dollar...

Comment: Sriracha is so important to me that if this were all that was left in the world, I would still eat it 

Comment: @user91988 So does a bun.  I still like the bun I make myself better than the one I buy for a dollar.

Comment: Every recipe will vary, naturally, but Wikipedia says Sriracha requires the following ingredients: a paste of chili peppers, distilled vinegar, garlic, sugar, and salt. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sriracha

Comment: From what I understand there is two ways to ferment something. One with vinegar and one without. It's called lacto fermentation. It's also not about price, it's about doing something fun and naturally. Play with your own recipe and flavors.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Do NOT eat this. You figured out right that the stuff on top is mold. The thing that makes mold dangerous is the mycotoxins produced by it and these will likely remain in the sauce even if you scrape off the furry stuff. So eating this comes with high risk of affecting your health. Move it to the trash bin right away.

I would recommend to try again with a recipe with vinegar added and also to use containers that are more appropriate for doing fermentation. This means to minimize the amount of air in the container that could possibly contain any spores and to minimize the surface of the food exposed to the air. So using a bottle will serve your purpose much better than the only half-full glasses on your pictures.

Also be very careful to sterilize the containers and tools getting in contact with the sauce before starting the fermentation.

Comment: Specifically, use a [fermentation lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermentation_lock) to let any gasses out while preventing any external air in.

Comment: As an alternative, you can ferment all kinds of things with [kimchi fermentation containers](http://crazykoreancooking.com/products/kimchi-fermenter).

Also, just a guess, it might help to ferment the ingredients in chunks, well covered by brine, so that only the brine is exposed to air, and blend it *at the end*. That's how I do hot sauce, anyhow.

Comment: I agree with everything you said whole-heatedly, except for the need for vinegar. Lacto-fermentation with salt and water alone is a totally viable method to ferment peppers for hot sauce, as long as the concentration is correct and the other safety precautions you mention are followed.

Comment: I would also rinse the container with very hot water before using it

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall Sriracha traditionally contains vinegar. Leaving it out, while fine, will result in a different type of "hot sauce" than what OP is seeking to reproduce it seems.

Comment: @SnakeDoc vinegar (and sugar for that matter) might be important to get the desired flavor, but they are still not necessary in the fermentation. Take a look at [this recipe](https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/chili-pepper-recipes/hot-sauces/homemade-sriracha-hot-sauce-recipe/) -- the peppers are fermented in salt brine, and sugar and vinegar are added only at the end.

Comment: @BenjaminKuykendall Fair enough. OP's recipe (posted in the question) does not contain any vinegar at all, which is partly why I raised that point. It will still be a fermented hot sauce, it just won't be the same flavor and texture profile of sriracha. The vinegar not only ads flavor, but it also helps preserve the sauce safety for months if done properly.

Comment: Traditional "canning" also emphatically boils/sterilizes the containers as a preliminary step...

Comment: @paulgarrett The containers and tools, yes, but the contents here cannot be cooked or they won't ferment.  The lactobacilli have to survive.